# SQL Agent Which user run the job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

SQl Server agent job.Is there any query to dispaly,which user run a particular job.
What are the action performed by a particular user on jobs.I am looking for user activities history on job running

Comment: Do you mean which user manually started the job, or what user the job runs under? Have you taken a look in the SQL Agent logs yet?

Comment: Try this `select [name], 
 [Description],
 SUSER_SNAME(OWNER_SID) AS Owner_name,
 LEFT([date_created],11)AS Date_Created,
 LEFT([date_Modified],11)AS Date_Modified,
 version_number,
 [Notify_level_EventLog]=
 CASE 
  WHEN notify_level_eventlog = 0 THEN 'No Log'
  WHEN notify_level_eventlog = 1 THEN 'When Job Succeeds'
  WHEN notify_level_eventlog = 2 THEN 'When Job Fails'
  WHEN notify_level_eventlog = 3 THEN 'On Completion regardless'
 END

from MSDB.dbo.sysjobs
ORDER BY [Owner_Name]`

Comment: Reference: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2850/querying-sql-server-agent-job-history-data/